# Zero result returned from oci_num_rows php oracle

Tags: php, sql, oracle

When i execute this query the result of oci_num_rows always zero , can any one help ?!

```
  $sql="SELECT * FROM apps.xx_fa_by_loc_mob where site_name ='$location' AND  tag_number='$data1'";

$res= oci_parse($link, $sql);
oci_execute($res);

$var=oci_num_rows($res);
echo $var;
```

any help would be great !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the [reason](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php):

```
Note:

This function does not return number of rows selected! For SELECT statements this function will return the number of rows, that were fetched to the buffer with oci_fetch*() functions.
```